# Onesignal NotificationOpened doesn't work in ios app

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, onesignal

I try to work with Onesignal Notifications in my ios app, created in Visual Studio with Xamarin. I want to make application open ViewController when user tap on notification, but it doesn't work. When user tap notification, app opens ViewController which was active when user application go to background.
Hope somebody show, where I made mistake
Here the code:

```
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    public static UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
    public override UIWindow Window {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        OneSignal.Current.StartInit("mykey")
            .InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
            .HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened)
            .EndInit();
        OneSignal.Current.IdsAvailable(IdsAvailable);            
        return true;
    }
    void IdsAvailable(string userID, string pushToken)
    {
        GlobalUserInfo._token = userID;
    }
    private static void HandleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
    {
        OSNotificationPayload payload = result.notification.payload;
        Dictionary<string, object> additionalData = payload.additionalData;

        if (additionalData != null)
        {
            UINavigationController NavigationController = (UINavigationController)Storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController();
            NotificationsViewController notificationsController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("NotificationsViewController") as NotificationsViewController;
            NavigationController.PushViewController(notificationsController, true);
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationsViewController** is simple list of all notification user received.

**UPDATED**
As I noticed, function HandleNotificationOpened does not work in iOS.

**UPDATED**
Error was found. I forgot, that I use OneSignal Init in other place. When I delete duplicate, HandleNotificationOpened begins work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find current root ViewController instead of creating a new instance. So please modify like this:

```
if (additionalData != null)
{
    UINavigationController NavigationController = (UINavigationController)Window.RootViewController;
    NotificationsViewController notificationsController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("NotificationsViewController") as NotificationsViewController;
    NavigationController.PushViewController(notificationsController, true);
}
```

Moreover, if the root ViewController is a UITabBarController, please present this view controller(NotificationsViewController).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use Window, because for HandleNotificationOpened it have to be static.

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus Then try to get Window by `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow`

Comment: Thanks, Visual Studio accepted this, but as I wrote in "update" to my post, look like "HandleNotificationOpened" function doesn't work itself. I added a global variable to project and changed it's value in "HandleNotificationOpened". But app showed, that after user tap push notification, this global didn't change.

Comment: Well, I fix the problem with "HandleNotificationOpened" function, and everything works correct. Thank you for help

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus OK, glad you solved it. I didn't use Onesignal before.  We often use `DidReceiveRemoteNotification()`, when we tap notification it will fire.

Comment: Once I started to create application, I wanted to use native push notifications for Android and iOS too, but Firebase worked very bad, push notifications came 5-10 minutes after. So I decided to use OneSignal, which work very good.